# How to authenticate user with Azure Active Directory using OAuth 2.0?

Tags: c#, authentication, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have a REST API written in C# and I need to authenticate with an existing Azure AD service. I currently have the username and password of the user wishing to authenticate. I need to authenticate with Azure AD and receive an access token from the server.

Can someone please point me in the direction of some articles/tutorials that explain how to do this?

Comment: You mean how to use OAuth 2.0 with Azure AD? The call-by-call process is described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx). The [Azure AD Authentication Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj573266.aspx) simplifies this process

Comment: The fact that you mention having the users credentials makes me nervous.  Could you add a bit more detail to your question.  Is the scenario: native app -> your REST API -> Azure AD Rest API.  Or is it: Web App -> your REST API -> Azure AD Rest API.  Or something else.  Depending on the exact scenario I can point you at samples that will prevent you from ever needing to handle the users credentials, which would be much safer from a security standpoint.

Answer (score 17):

You should avoid handling the users credentials.  There are serious security implications when collecting a users credentials that are mitigated by using OAuth 2.0 or OpenID Connect to get a token without directly handling the credentials.  Also, if you have your own credential collection UI then you may find that sign in fails in the future if multi-factor authentication is turned on. In that case, more information may be necessary to authenticate the user than you are collecting, a one time password for instance.  If you allow Azure AD to present the authentication experience via OAuth 2.0 or OpenID Connect, then you are insulated from the specific authentication method being employed.  Collecting the users Azure AD credentials is a bad practice to be avoided if at all possible.

I don't have enough detail on the exact scenario to be confident that the following sample applies, but it will at least provide a good starting point.  This sample shows how to create a native app that calls a REST API that can then call an Azure resource in the safest way possible.

https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebAPI-OnBehalfOf-DotNet

You can find lots of other samples here that can be used to construct a solution for your particular scenario.

https://github.com/AzureADSamples

If you provide some more detail I can give more specific guidance.

Comment: Hi, I have an Android app, that sends through a username and password to my REST API. The REST API then needs to check if this username and password combination is correct using an existing Azure AD server. If it is correct, the REST API will handle the generation of an access token that the app will use to communicate with my REST API.

Comment: Please avoid transporting the username and password.  Everywhere you handle the username and password is another potential place for the users account to be compromised.  The tokens returned from AAD are constrained to a particular scope.  If one of these tokens is compromised the severity of the compromise is considerably less than a compromised username password.  Why are you collecting the username password directly?  Can this be changed?

Comment: There are compliance-related situations where apps need to validate credentials in-app for a request.  There seems no way around this without acquiring creds from the client app and then validating with Azure on the server (C# in client app).

Comment: I'd like to better understand your compliance situation.  Getting a token from AAD implies that the credentials were valid.

Comment: Great points on not transporting user credentials within your app. Thanks @RichRandall

Comment: Not certain why this is getting up voted. Answering a question by giving your opinion of the question isn't an answer.

Answer (score 4):

See: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/

Summary:
Create a UserCredential

```
UserCredential uc = new UserCredential(user, password);
```

Call one of the AcquireToken() functions with the UserCredential

```
public AuthenticationResult AcquireToken(string resource, string clientId, UserCredential userCredential);
public Task<AuthenticationResult> AcquireTokenAsync(string resource, string clientId, UserCredential userCredential);
```

Comment: @ivan.petrovic **Resource:** The App ID URI of the web API (secured resource). To find the App ID URI of the web API, in the Azure Management Portal, click Active Directory, click the directory, click the application and then click Configure. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code/

Comment: From the same article: You can only use those flows from a **native** client. A confidential client, such as a web site, cannot use direct user credentials.

Comment: If you look at the accepted answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40498384/adal-v3-how-to-authenticate-using-userpasswordcredential you see how you can construct a RAW POST request to use user credentials to get a token. This works anywhere you can create a HttpClient object to make the request...

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer allows the application to have access to the user's username and password .. a better way would be to let the credential provider validate and return a token which the application can ask the provider to validate.  In that way the user's information stays between the provider and the user.

Comment: @nmishr in the original question the application has the username and password.