# Azure Active Directory OAuth Resource Owner Password Credentials Flow

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

On one of the project I'm working on I need to use the Resource Owner Password Credentials Flow and the official docummentation doesn't support it : https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/aeab0a46-4da1-4300-be9c-3be418f07a5b.aspx/ it only supports Authorizartion Code and Client Credentials. A google search led me to this [github link](https://github.com/nordvall/TokenClient/wiki/OAuth-2-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-grant-in-AzureAd) that says Resource Owner Password Credentials  could be done, I tested it and it worked fine but I don't know if it will be available in the future. So,  does anyone knows ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a fully supported flow and will be for the foreseeable future.  However, use of the flow is discouraged for both security and functionality reasons.  Please see the following answer for a bit more depth on why it is discouraged.

[How to authenticate user with Azure Active Directory using OAuth 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28580848/how-to-authenticate-user-with-azure-active-directory-using-oauth-2-0/28597758#28597758)

Use of this flow should be reserved primarily for command line tools or scenarios in which an interactive flow is simply not possible.

You might consider using the Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) if you don't want to implement the OAuth 2.0 interactions yourself.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151135.aspx

Comment: Hi Rich, thanks a lot for the quick answer. I'm conscious of the security issues that this flow involves, there is a business and technical reason why I need to use that flow. Regards, Rodrigo.

Comment: Actually Rich, I would like to talk to you about this : the thing is that I have a Web API that is consumed by a mobile client (android, iOS) and there is a functional requirement to avoid the user to re enter his credentials if he wants to use the application for example 24 hs later. How you think could be the best way for handling this with Authorization Code Grant Flow ? Thanks a lot. Rodrigo

Comment: @RodrigoLongo, I am happy to help.  This sounds like it could be split in to a separate question that others might be interested in.  Also, I don't think I have enough space here to answer the question comprehensively.  Would you mind creating a new question for it?

Comment: Thanks Rich, this is the link to the new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29151132/azure-active-directory-oauth-authentication-with-authorization-code-grant-flow