# Changing expired password(s) using Azure Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have the following Python code to authenticate against the Graph API

```
import requests

def login(tenant_name, client_id, client_secret, username, password):
     url = 'https://login.windows.net/' + tenant_name + '/oauth2/token'
     payload = {
             'grant_type': 'password',
             'username': username + '@' + tenant_name,
             'password': password,
             'client_id': client_id,
             'client_secret': client_secret,
             'resource': 'https://graph.windows.net'
     }

     r = requests.post(url, data=payload)

    return r.json()
```

If I have user, whose password has expired, I get a response(as expected):

```
{
 'timestamp': '2015-09-15 02:59:26Z',
 'trace_id': '8abff845-6941-4867-9729-15626c23330f',
 'submit_url': None, 
 'correlation_id': '81184c06-2627-4bca-82e3-76aab7713a5f', 
 'error_description': 'AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50055: Password is expired.
Trace ID: 8abff845-6941-4867-9729-15626c23330f
Correlation ID: 81184c06-2627-4bca-82e3-76aab7713a5f
Timestamp: 2015-09-15 02:59:26Z',
 'context': None,
 'error': 'user_password_expired', 
 'error_codes': [70002, 50055]
}
```

Graph API provides use an endpoint to [reset a password](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/users-operations#BasicoperationsonusersResetauserspassword), but to do so, I need a valid token (to make a PATCH request to the endpoint mentioned in the documentation) and since I couldn't login, I don't have one.

What is the right way to change a user password on expiry using the Azure Graph API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

At least not with the [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3) (`grant_type=password`) flow, where you only have the end-user's credentials (though really, there are very few cases where this flow is a good choice--see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26795582/325697) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29110987/325697) for more).

The user needs to be directed to Azure AD's web interface (in a browser/web view) to authenticate and change their password.

Comment: Thanks much for all the information, that makes sense.