# Microsoft Graph Authentication

Tags: python, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I’m building an application in Python which can retrieve data from Azure AD. This data can require either Application permissions or Delegated permissions. I had a success retrieving data which needs only Application permissions. However, in order to retrieve data which needs delegated permission, I am trying to use OAuth2. Is it possible to get authenticated with Microsoft Graph using OAuth2 but not having the user sign in using the web page, but instead supplying the user credentials through the Python script itself?

Note: I want to use Microsoft Graph API (v1.0 and beta) and not Azure AD Graph API.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Active Directory OAuth Resource Owner Password Credentials Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29102820/azure-active-directory-oauth-resource-owner-password-credentials-flow)

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi this is a different case. I'm trying to authenticate to Graph API (v1.0 and beta) and not Azure AD API. Also, I'm looking for something in Python.

Comment: It doesn't matter which endpoint you are trying to authenticate to, the flow you are looking for is the Resource Owner Password Credentials, and likely you will need to implement this using pure  REST calls, which is documented.

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi also, that is in C#, of which I pretty much have no knowledge :(

Comment: @Raj, here are some options for Python authentication to Microsoft Graph which may be helpful: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/python-sample-auth/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have registered and configured (api permissions) your azure app and you have copied the apps "client id" and "client secret" you can define a class that holds your session.
The following code works for my app:

```
import json
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from oauthlib.oauth2 import BackendApplicationClient


class SharepointSession(object):
    """ Base Class without credentials, use real credentials in derived Classes
    or instances
    """
    api_uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
    api_version = "v1.0"
    scope = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]
    directory_id = ""  # - tenant id
    token_url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{}/oauth2/v2.0/token"
    sites_url = "{}/{}/sites".format(api_uri, api_version)
    site = document_name = app_name = client_id = client_secret = ""
    site_id = None
    doc_id = None

    def __init__(self):
        """  """

    def getTokenizedSession(self):
        """
        OAuth2 to get access token
        First set up a backend client, mind to set grant_type
        build a OAuth2 Session with the client
        get access token

        Mind: python 3.x oauthlib requires scope params on more calls than py 2.x
        """
        client = BackendApplicationClient(
            client_id=self.client_id, scope=self.scope, grant_type="client_credentials")

        session = OAuth2Session(client=client, scope=self.scope)
        # fill access token
        token = session.fetch_token(token_url=self.token_url.format(self.directory_id),
                                    client_id=self.client_id,
                                    scope=self.scope,
                                    client_secret=self.client_secret)
        self.session = session
        self.token = token
        return session, token

    def getSiteId(self):
        # get the site id
        ae = "{}/myonline.sharepoint.com:/sites/{}:".format(
            self.sites_url, self.site)
        rt = self.session.get(ae)
        response = json.loads(rt.text)
        self.site_id = response.get("id")
        return self.site_id

    def someOtherMethod(self):
        """         ...             """
```

Now you can instantiate the session class with the credentials copied from your azure app registration i.e. "directory id" (same as tenant id), "client id" and "client secret"
like this:

```
mysp_session = SharepointSession()
mysp_session.directory_id = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-YYYY-ZZZZ-XXXXXXXXX"
mysp_session.site = "MySitename"
mysp_session.document_name = "Testlist"
mysp_session.client_id = r"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
mysp_session.client_secret = r"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

# connect 
session, token = mysp_session.getTokenizedSession()

# do your business logic
mysp_session.getSiteId()
....
mysp_session.someOtherMethod()
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible - but keep in mind that there are two Azure AD endpoints for application registration!

Try registering an application on the AAD V2.0 endpoint (apps.dev.microsoft.com), and then use a 'password' grant_type in your request.

Here are the steps you need:

- Register your app on the AAD v2.0 endpoint, and generate a password (take
  note of this)
- Assign your required permissions (in this case, delegated)
- As a callback URL I'd suggest using postman's Oauth2 callback URL first so you can debug what you're doing: https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback
- Important! If any of those permissions require admin consent, you MUST consent to them first to make the app available. This requires the admin user to sign in once.

Once consent has been given, here's a what your request needs to get a bearer token as a prototype:

```
    POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token
    Request body (application/x-www-form-urlencoded): 
    grant_type=[password]
    username=[user email address]
    password=[user password]
    resource=https://graph.microsoft.com
    client_id=[your newly registered application ID] 
    client_secret=[application password you noted during registration]
```

If successful, you'll get the bearer & refresh token as a response.

[image: Successful password grant authentication response]
Hope this helps,

Ben

Answer (score 0):

You need an Azure AD application to be able to authenticate with Graph API. A native Azure AD app and the flow and considerations described here work for ADAL.net. I use it to provision Microsoft Teams unattended: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/

I guess for Python you should have a look at ADAL for Python: https://github.com/introp-software/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python-old/blob/master/README.md

I think that the username/password auth is only possible with a native Azure AD app and not the web/web api types.