# Microsoft Graph Authentication - Delegated permission

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-authentication

I am able to access resources from Microsoft Graph using [Get access without user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service). However, this method does not allow me to access resources which require delegated permissions.

I also tried to use the [Get access on behalf of a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user) method, but it will require my user to sign in through a webpage, which is **not desired** in my scenario.

Is it possible to generate an authorization code with a long life time (possibly over a year) and use that code to request an access token, which can then be used to get resources that require **delegated permissions?**

Note: I know generating an authorization code with such a long life time is not a good idea, but this code will be used by the back-end program to access resources and not the user. So I do not want the user sign in page to pop up. Looking to implement this in Java.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your goal here? Are you okay with the user signing in once with a webpage, as long as they don't need to sign in again for another year?

Comment: Ideally no, but if there's no other option, then I might be OK with that too.

Comment: You are going to get the same answer as you did in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45601581/microsoft-graph-authentication) thread which you also opened. The solution here is to use "Resource Owner Password Credentials Flow" if you want to skip the sign in page, otherwise, you can use [Refresh Tokens](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes) if you acquire the first token normally. No one here is going to write a Python sample for you for Resource Owner Password Credentials Flow. You will need to do that yourself.

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi I'm not looking for someone to write code for me. I am just looking for directions. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Here are some pointers. [1](https://dzimchuk.net/protecting-your-apis-with-azure-active-directory/) [2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2016/09/25/resource-owner-password-credentials-grant-in-azure-ad-oauth/) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44466189/oauth2-resource-owner-password-grant-via-api) [4](https://www.google.com/search?q=Resource+Owner+Password+Credentials+Grant+azure+active+directory)

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi these are helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use delegated permission, the end user needs to sign in interactively through an OAuth2.0 flow.

Now, you can use a user's creds with the [Resource Owner Credentials Flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-37) which is simply posting the username/password to Azure AD and getting tokens back. This path is not recommended as it's brittle (For example, MFA will not work) and requires your app to manage the user's credentials.

Your best bet is to create some kind of sign in experience for your users that allows them to sign in and consent to your application. Refresh tokens in Azure AD have a [lifetime of ***until-revoked***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#token-types) meaning they can last as long as a year if not longer. The bottleneck you'll hit is the end user's password expiring which would lead them to need to sign in again.

For some help with this, Azure AD has an [ADAL4j library](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java) you can use.  I've also written a small [Spring MVC Java code sample](https://github.com/danieldobalian/AADv2JavaMVC) for the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint (Microsoft Accounts + Azure AD Accounts) that uses a 3rd party library.