# Python Requests Microsoft Graph API Authentication

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, python-requests, microsoft-graph-api

I'm having issues receiving the bearer token using Python for the Microsoft Graph API. Here is what I have so far:

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
'Content-Type': 'x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Authorization': 'Basic'
}

data = {
"grant_type": "client_credentials",
"client_id" :"<client_id>",
"client_secret": "<client_secret>",
"resource": "https://graph.microsoft.com"
}

r = requests.post('<token_address>', headers=headers, data=data)
print(r.text)
```

I have it worked in Postman, through x-www-form-urlencoded, but can't seem to get it working in Python. It returns The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'. I realize the problem probably has to do with needed the data converted, but I am not sure where to start.

Comment: Try this:
[similar Problem and Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59874434/8646727)

Answer (score 3):

You're sending some invalid headers in your request:

- The `Content-Type` should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` not `x-www-form-urlencoded`.
- You shouldn't be sending an `Authorization` header at all.

Technically, since `requests.post` sends data as form encoded by default, you can safely remove your `headers` from the request:

```
payload = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': '<client_id>',
    'client_secret': '<client_secret>',
    'resource': 'https://graph.microsoft.com',
    }
r = requests.post('https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token', data=payload)
print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that OAuth expects the body to be URL-encoded, like this:

```
data = "grant_type=client_credentials"
    + "&client_id=<client_id>"
    + "&client_secret=<client_secret>"
    + "&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still returning the same error.