# Azure AD Login Without user browser redirect?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, azure, adal

I managed to get Azure AD Authentication to work by using the sample apps from [ADAL4J library from GitHub](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java).

[Here it is working.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rg_DDWviJ_o&hd=1)

My question is:
Can the same result be accomplished without the redirect to the Microsoft page?
The customer wants to use his own internal login page.

I'm thinking some sort of behind the scenes POST request to the same URL, and getting the reply. This means my app will see the user credentials, I am ok with that.

Is this supported by Azure AD?

Environment:
Java server side (Spring), AngularJS UI.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you come up with a solution?

Comment: ginalster no, I didn't find any solution, but I also stopped searching because the integration with Azure was postponed for later. (not sure how much later, it's been almost one year :) ).

Comment: alex, depending on what you are looking for. Azure AD B2C is in preview. We just want to handle the login flow ourselves, no through external form redirects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The redirect is necessary.  Only AAD should be collecting AAD credentials.  See this answer for more information on why that is:

[How to authenticate user with Azure Active Directory using OAuth 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28580848/how-to-authenticate-user-with-azure-active-directory-using-oauth-2-0/28597758#28597758)

Comment: I disagree. Redirects create user confusion. We want to create the full user experience without the customer leaving our site. We want to take advantage of secure technologies though. Don't want to rely on asp membership and such.