# Trying O365 Authentication in Xamarin forms app

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, adal, o365-flow

We are new to O365 Authentication and trying to authenticate the user.

Here i am getting this error while trying to login with, office 365.

Create app in active directory add app id and return urls in app, and this is the document I followed, https://blog.xamarin.com/put-adal-xamarin-forms/

here is the error we are getting,

AADSTS70002: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion'
Trace ID: e580114e-2dd9-4cc4-b903-6cef743a2900
Correlation ID: 6e58ff9d-bea4-4ad3-9fe3-e27c92fc9597
Timestamp: 2018-12-05 12:51:23Z

{System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). ---> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalException: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS70002: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion'\r\nTrace ID: e580114e-2dd9-4cc4-b903-6cef743a2900\r\nCorrelation ID: 6e58ff9d-bea4-4ad3-9fe3-e27c92fc9597\r\nTimestamp: 2018-12-05 12:51:23Z","error_codes":[70002],"timestamp":"2018-12-05 12:51:23Z","trace_id":"e580114e-2dd9-4cc4-b903-6cef743a2900","correlation_id":"6e58ff9d-bea4-4ad3-9fe3-e27c92fc9597"}: Unknown error
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---}

Comment: From the error ,that may miss some info when request.You can try the OfficeDev GitHub sample: https://github.com/OfficeDev/XamarinAndroidO365 to test and check the problem.

Comment: As per that example, we are passing appid and redirect url, the error is more talking about, client_secret or client_assertion, which we don't have for app

Comment: OK , trying to Change to native client.You can refer to this link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28580848/how-to-authenticate-user-with-azure-active-directory-using-oauth-2-0/28597758#28597758

Comment: Yeah, Working fine with Native client app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ,Maybe you have registered your app as a confidential client (web app or web api).

You cannot authenticate with username and password when the app is a confidential client. Only public clients, sometimes known as native clients, can do U/P authentication.

Trying to Change to native client.

[Refer to this link to try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28580848/how-to-authenticate-user-with-azure-active-directory-using-oauth-2-0/28597758#28597758)